# Writing an equation for a log function given the graph

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

I have the following graph for a logarithmic function $f$:

[image]

I don't know any thing about writing an equation for a logarithmic function by knowing it's graph. All what I know is how to draw a graph for a logarithmic function equation.

**How can I write an equation for the graph above or any another graph-logarithmic function graph-?**

Answer (score 1):

You pick a functional form with some number of parameters.  "A logarithmic function" is not a sufficient description.  Seeing the vertical asymptote, I would guess th form you want is $y=a \log (3-bx)$  To get the point $(-1,0)$, you need $b=\frac 34$.  Now find the $a$ that fits best.  If that doesn't satisfy, try another form.  If it sounds like a bit of art, it is.  You can use root-finders for the parameters once you choose a form.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are told that you face a logarithmic function, you know by inspection that there is an infinite branch at x=3. Then, the function must be something like y = a + b Log[3-x]. Now, since you have two parameters (a and b), just use two of the data points of your graph; this leads to two linear equations you can simply solve. Just use the third data point to check that you reached the right answer. Can you continue with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The equation must be undefined for x = 3 so log(x-3) will be part of the function.  Use the first point (2, -2) to make the log term "log 1" as log((2-3)/-1).  Use the second point to determine the base of the log, Log((1-3)/-1) is log 2 so the base is 2.  Put it all together as y = -2 + log base 2 ((x-3)/-1).